MS Project, Group resources
I'm looking for a way to create "Resource" groups" in MS Project.
Problem:
I have 4 Vessels, with different day rates and different Fuel consumption. I would need to Create a resource, a resource group, that shows Fuel consumption and Vessel usage for, per Vessel.
Today I need to add both Vessel and Fuel to each task. And - if I change the Vessel, or updates it's performance (Fuel consumption) I need to change every row on which I have used that Vessel.
Best would be if I could create a group - using A Vessel dayrate(Work resource) + a fuel volume (Material resource).
So - By grouping "Vessel_1" and "Fuel x 3.5" I would get a new Resource Containing both Fuel and Day rate. "Vessel_2" and "Fuel x 4.2" would create another Resource - with a bit more fuel consumption.
I could then also build the "Vessel_1 Transit" and "Vessel_1 Operation" resources - since the day rate is the same, but Fuel comsumption varies, I can easily build new resources from existing.
BUT - How to do this in MS Project??!

Bobo. First understand that Project does NOT have a day rate. All resource (work type) is per minute regardless of how the standard rate is entered on the Resource Sheet. So, for example, if "vessel A" is $100/day and is assigned to a task that has 1.5 days duration, then the vessel will cost $150. The only way to get a true day rate is with a VBA macro, which I have done.
If your tasks are in one day increments (or less), then you could use the Cost/Use rate for your vessels. The Cost/Use value is applied each time that resource is assigned to a task whether the task is one minute long or 1 year long.
As far as fuel consumption, if you are looking for consumption as gallons/hr (or liters/hr) then that is how you would enter the material label on the Resource Sheet.
You can't group a work type resource (vessel) and a material resource (fuel) as a single group resource, they must each be separately assigned to a task. You can "join" them (for identification) using the Group field on the Resource Sheet (i.e. "A resource") but is not a group resource.
You also mention something about a "transit" and "operation" resource. I'm not sure what those are exactly, perhaps an example would help.

Hi - and thanks for your reply! I am aware that MS PRoject doesn't really work with a "Day rate" - but it's possible to create a Resource of the Work type, that has  a cost per hour. Making sure that the Calendars align - that solves that...
And yes, I add the Material resource in m3 (Lots of fuel...), and when I assign it I use Consumption "/h", and that solves the Fuel per our...
But If I understnad you correct, and that was my assumption even if I was hoping for something else, so doesn't Project support creating a new resource by Grouping other resources. To bad, would have been ++

Bobbo. Correct, a resource is either work type, material type or cost type and they cannot be combined as a mixed type resource (i.e. each must be separately assigned). Work resources CAN be combined into a group resource. For example, let's say you have 3 resources, Joe, Bill & Tom, and they are all carpenters doing framing. Instead of separately identifying 3 carpenters each with a 100% Max Unit availability, a group resource "carpenters" could be identified with a Max Unit availability of 300%.
